# How does clCreateBuffer use CL_MEM_*_HOST_PTR for kernel's output?

Tags: buffer, opencl

I tried an implicit way to read OpenCL kernel's results from device to host:

```
input_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int) * n, input_data, &_err);
output_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int) * n, output_data, &_err);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(...);
```

In the code snippet above, I could get correct results from kernel in `output_data`. However, for the `output_buffer` creation, after I changed `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` into `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`, the `output_data` stayed the same as if the kernel hadn't been executed. As I know, `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` works for the transmission from host to device in a way that it firstly copies the contents pointed by `input_data` into a different memory space, then `input_buffer` gets kernel's input from this new space. I doubt if the same thing happens for the `output_buffer`, and it copies kernel's results to somewhere else but doesn't move them into the space pointed by `output_data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to OpenCL standard:

- `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` indicates that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to copy the data from memory referenced by `host_ptr`. It doesn't indicate, on which side memory will be allocated.
- `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` indicates that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to use memory referenced by `host_ptr` as the storage bits for the memory object. OpenCL implementations are allowed to cache the buffer contents pointed to by `host_ptr` in device memory. This cached copy can be used when kernels are executed on a device.

So, if you use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, data interconnection between Device & Host is transparent. No guarantee can be made, that any amount of memory on Device side will be allocated.

Taking back to your code snippet:

- `input_buffer = clCreateBuffer(...)` will lead to allocation of `sizeof(int) * n` bytes on Device side.
- `output_buffer = clCreateBuffer(...)` will not lead to memory allocation on Device side. Your OpenCL implementation may somehow cache content of Host-side memory, on which `output_data` points, but you will never now.

Comment: Thank you, Roman. I cannot understand the "transparent" thing. Does that mean if you write on device side will directly change the host? One more question, in your first item, you said that on which side memory would be allocated is not deterministic, while in the 3rd and 4th items, the allocations happen on device side. Are these two allocations same?

Comment: CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR should be used with other flag, which will determine, where object will be allocated. If you don't use CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR or CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, memory will be allocated on Device side.

Comment: @troore Transparent means it will get copied without any user intervention. However, in order to ensure that the data is consistent is needed a map/unmap cycle.

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan This is helpful to me. Although it doesn't affect program results, could you provide some references on the relationship between these flags and locations where memory is located?

Comment: Take a look at clCreateBuffer & clCreateImage functions description at http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/ There is complete & exhaustive explanation of cl_mem_flags

Answer (score 3):

With OpenCL 1.x, after you run your kernel you must use either `clEnqueueMapBuffer` or `clEnqueueReadBuffer` to get the data back into host memory for further use by the CPU. There's no way around it.

Comment: Actually, I've got correct results without any clEnqueue command. The kernel I used is vector addition, very simple. My test hardware is AMD A10-5800K APU with Radeon HD Graphics, and OpenCL version is 1.2.

Comment: I've just tried clEnqueueNDRangeKernel for memory object, which was created with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, and result is visible on Host side at once, without any mapping or reading (on discrete GPU). BTW, I didn't found anything about reading or mapping in standard. Can you please give a reference, that there is no way around?

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan, do you see anything in the standard that would indicate the other way around? Since SVM doesn't occur until OpenCL 1.x, that's a pretty strong indication it isn't part of 1.x.

Comment: @troore, that's great, but non-portable and it could break with any driver update.

Comment: @Dithermaster I see. That could happen. Thanks for your information.